# UITableView and two RSS feeds

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to parse two RSS feeds at the same time using a for loop, but the thing is, when the first RSS feed is parsed  completely and allocated in the table view, parsing the second feed causes the table view to be overwritten by that second feed, showing the second RSS only. Is there a way to show both  the feeds? The code is below.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([stories count] == 0) {
        NSString * path;
        path=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.marshillchurch.org/media/luke/feed/vodcast_video","http://www.marshillchurch.org/media/luke/feed/vodcast_audio",nil];

        //[self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
        [self refresh:path];
    }

    cellSize = CGSizeMake([newsTable bounds].size.width, 60);
}
- (NSString *)refresh:(NSString *)path
{
    for(NSString *feed in path)
    {
        [self parseXMLFileAtURL:feed];
     // NSLog(@"the path is great:%@",feed);    
    }
}
- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
{   
    stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];


    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    [rssParser setDelegate:self];
    [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [rssParser parse];



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the "stories" array every time you parse the XML (I assume that you are using the stores array in your tableview datasource). You should take a look at NSMutableArray's addObject method.

Comment: i ve tried using addObject method in parserDidEndElement,der is no change in the simulator,except for some warings NSMutableArray may not respond to addObject

Comment: Can you show your code from parserDidEndElement? If you getting a warning about NSMutableArray not responding to addObject then you are doing something wrong there.

Comment: (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
//NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName); if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) { // save values to an item, then store that item into the array... [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"]; [item

Comment: setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"]; [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"description"]; [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"]; [item setObject:currentImage forKey:@"podcastLink1"]; [item setObject:currentPicture forKey:@"href"]; [item setObject:currentImage1 forKey:@"podcastLink2"]; [stories addObject:[item copy]]; }

Comment: Where do your first declare stories? It is a property? When you get an error about NSMutableArray and addObject does it say anything else?

Comment: ive declared stories array in rootviewcontroller header file...i don hav any problem with stories array.when i change the setObject to add object for currentLink,currentDate.....etc its gives me a warning wen i run in simulator getting the same old result